# How to write an environment wrapping document environment

Tags: environments, programming

I'm working on wrapping up some patterns used in my research group for creating posters. Since we're using beamer and beamerposter to make these, all documents go essentially like this:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

\begin{document}
\begin{frame}

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I'd like to simplify this to like:

```
\documentclass{ourposter}

\begin{poster}

\end{poster}
```

So I tried to implement the poster environment as `\newenvironment{poster}{\begin{document}\begin{frame}}{\end{frame}\end{document}}`.

Unfortunately, that seems to be the wrong thing to do, since `latex` responds with: LaTeX Error: \begin{poster} on input line 10 ended by \end{document}. I can work around it by replacing the begin/end document with `\document`/`\enddocument`, but I'm a bit wary of that.

Is the right approach to just sidestep the LaTeX environment stuff and use the commands directly, or is there a better approach here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In general something like

```
\documentclass{ourposter}
\begin{document}
\end{document}
```

with

```
\AtBeginDocument{\begin{frame}}
\AtEndDocument{\end{frame}}
```

in your class should work. With a document classes based on `beamer`, however, it doesn't work. It appears the beamer `frame` environment is touchy about how it is called and when it is started and closed. With the `beamer` class you can do the following

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\AfterEndPreamble{\begin{frame}}
\let\myenddocument\enddocument
\def\enddocument{\end{frame}\myenddocument}
\begin{document}
hello world
\end{document}
```

Comment: I'd agree that this is the more regular LaTeX syntax.  The document is enclosed with `\begin{document}...\end{document}`, not `\begin{` *document class name* `}...\end{` *document class name* `}`.

Comment: Using `poster` instead of `document` is based on things like letter.cls using `\begin{letter}`. Your solution works, I guess, but I'd also like to add an optional argument that gets passed to the `\begin{frame}`. For a presentation Beamer's default of vertical centering is good, but for posters sometimes we're going to prefer `\begin{document}\begin{frame}[t]` which is was planning to expose as `\begin{poster}[t]`. Is that possible with `\AtBeginDocument`?

Comment: @arnsholt the letter class still requires `\begin{document}` and works like your original usage of `\begin{document}\begin{frame}`. You didn't ask for a way to rename the `frame` environment, rather your question suggests you want only one `\begin{}`. As for options, why not add it as an option to your class `\documentclass[t]{ourposter}`

Comment: Oh, my mistake. And adding the alignment as a package option makes perfect sense. There'll always be just a single frame, after all. Cheers!

Comment: I was a bit too quick it seems. Doing this gives me the error "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \test.". Some googling led me to try `\AtBeginDocument{\begin{frame}[fragile]}` but that simply moves the error a bit (or so it seems): "! Illegal parameter number in definition of \beamer@test.". Any idea what's happening?

Comment: @arnsholt see the modified answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\newenvironment{poster}
  {\document\begin{frame}}
  {\end{frame}\enddocument}
\begin{poster}
\frametitle{My Frame}
foo \pause bar
\end{poster}
```

However, I cannot see that this make really sense ...